# Will Linux Multi-booting with Ubuntu 10.04 and 9.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, grub, partitioning

I've currently organised my laptop's hard disk using the multi-booting template idea, as shown here:-
http://www.linuxforu.com/teach-me/tips-tricks/distromania-a-multi-booting-template/

Currently the 'Distro1' is Ubuntu 9.10 but I would want to add Ubuntu 10.04 as the 2nd Distro in sda7.  According to the above article, I would have to install the GRUB on the 2nd Distro's root (/) partition rather than in MBR.  Since Ubuntu 10.04 has changed its bootloader to Grub2, will the above multi-boot template idea still work?  If not, then how do I achieve what I want (i.e. a multi-boot setup where, in addition to the current Ubuntu 9.10 Distro, I can choose to boot into Ubuntu 10.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another partition for Ubuntu 10.04's `/` partition, and proceed to install grub2 to the MBR itself, no need to write it to the root partition. grub2 will detect all OS installations and will add them to the list automatically and you can select what version you want to boot into.

Comment: Agreed. Just use grub2 on the MBR to boot into 9.10.

Answer (score 0):

Have not read your link but from experience I can say that booting two different Ubuntus is not a problem.  I just edited the partitions on 9.10 to give the new OS some room, installed 10.04 in the newly created space it worked fine. I can't guarantee success on your system but it's certainly possible without much effort.