# How to upgrade Ubuntu 9.10 to 12.04 without causing problems for 10.04, my main distro version?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, multi-boot, ubuntu-12.04

I have a laptop with a dual boot setup with Ubuntu 10.04 as my primary distro and 9.10 as the secondary distro.

I want to upgrade 9.10 to 12.04 and keep 10.04 as is.  Eventually I might want 12.04 to be my primary boot, but not for the time being.

I could just go ahead and upgrade 9.10, but I'm afraid this would interfere with my primary distro.

What is the the best method for achieving what I want?

Comment: How are you achieving this side-by-side installation?

Comment: As shown here- http://superuser.com/questions/190057/will-linux-multi-booting-with-ubuntu-10-04-and-9-10

Answer (score 1):

i dont see why upgrading your ubuntu 9 installation should have any effect at all on ubuntu 10. They are 2 different installs on 2 different partitions. One shouldn't affect the other.